# Pyspark Getting the last date of the previous quarter based on Today's Date

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-workbooks, foundry-code-repositories

In a code repo, using pyspark, I'm trying to use today's date and based on this I need to retrieve the last day of the prior quarter. This date would be then used to filter out data in a data frame. I was trying to create a dataframe in a code repo and that wasn't working. My code works in Code Workbook. This is my code workbook code.

```py
import datetime as dt
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


def unnamed():
    date_df = spark.createDataFrame([(dt.date.today(),)], ['date'])
    date_df = date_df \
        .withColumn('qtr_start_date', F.date_trunc('quarter', F.col('date'))) \
        .withColumn('qtr_date', F.date_sub(F.col('qtr_start_date'), 1))

    return date_df
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I was trying to create a dataframe in a code repo and that wasn't working" -  hey for next time, it will be easier to help you if you say _how_ it wasn't working. Did you get an error message, did it give you the wrong dates, or was there something else that was wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the following code to run successfully in a Code Repository:

```py
from transforms.api import transform_df, Input, Output
import datetime as dt
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


@transform_df(
    Output("/my/output/dataset"),
)
def my_compute_function(ctx):
    date_df = ctx.spark_session.createDataFrame([(dt.date.today(),)], ['date'])
    date_df = date_df \
        .withColumn('qtr_start_date', F.date_trunc('quarter', F.col('date'))) \
        .withColumn('qtr_date', F.date_sub(F.col('qtr_start_date'), 1))

    return date_df
```

You'll need to pass the `ctx` argument into your transform, and you can make the `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` directly using the underlying `spark_session` variable.

If you already have the date column available in your input, you'll just need to make sure it's the `Date` type so that the `F.date_trunc` call works on the correct type.